# Xcode source control not synced with git status (and with repo)

Tags: xcode, git

**EDIT**: Thanks @RobMac - XCode restart did solved it. Good luck for all

---

Looks like a bug...

I Have two files in **Xcode** that marked in the source control with `question mark` (so it's untracked files)

When I do `git status` i get:

> On branch develop Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
>   Untracked files:   (use "git add ..." to include in what will be
>   committed)
>
> Podfile.lock
>
> Pods/

The files are not listed.

I try to workaround in Xcode by right click and "Add "FileName.swift""
Or to commit them in the commit window.
Both do NOTHING!!

When I look at the repo in BitBucket I see the files in their last revision... So It's great...
The problem is only the files status in Xcode

How can I overcome this?

Thanks!

Comment: Xcode has its own .gitignore and git config check it to see it content. There might be something for those files

Comment: @CodeWizrad but I committed them with Xcode and it worked.. it's just their status that wrong!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Late answer, but I had this happen to me. This is what I tried without success:

1. Closed existing project, not Xcode
2. Made changes on the command line (moved/deleted files)
3. Used GIT on the command line
4. Opened up existing project
5. Everything messed up
6. List item

**I fixed it by completely closing out of Xcode and then opening up project again.**

Comment: Thx, but I tried this, it didn’t solve my problem. And the problem is gone now so I can’t check it out.

Comment: It HAPPENED AGAIN!! Thanks - you resolved my issue - nothing worked except your solution!! =]

Comment: I fixed it by closing the Xcode project/workspace, then issue `git status`.

Answer (score 2):

did you check `ls -al`?

checkout how many `.git` directories exist

if you have mistake you did `git init` more than you expect because of xocde

Comment: I have only one .git folder, I never did git init manually.. My project is not new.. it's very old.. The problem is very new

Comment: i know, but sometime you did not CLI `git init` you only generate new folder it has been executed

Comment: can I do anything to track the problem?

Comment: just input cli `git status` every folder you generated

Comment: or find out have you any `.gitignore` what you didn't generate if we wanna use some kind of IDE. we have to know about it very exactly

Comment: I have a global gitignore that I set which excludes Xcode user state file

Comment: This was helpful for me. I had originally made a git repo with a new Xcode project, then created another at a higher directory level when creating my new remote (doh)!